# Changes for local .NET application to work without the debug on?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a .Net application. Works fine when I'm in debug mode.

When i stop the debug, i get next message Oops! "browser" could not connect to localhost:someport.

How can i prevent this behaviour?

Comment: Because when you stop debugging, VS must turn off IIS express (or whatever it's using). So you can't get to it.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Of course this is the problem. Is there some configuration i can do to let IIS turned on anytime ?

Comment: The odd thing is when I do this on my machine, it still runs (I just compile it, not run it, and it works fine). What VS version are you using? Also is this just normal asp.net or MVC?

Comment: I don't have how to deploy my application right now and i want to work another 4-5 hours. And the debug on thing is annoying.

Comment: MVC application on VS RC 2013.

Comment: I'm guessing that you debug with IE, and IIS express launches (seen from icon in notification area on the taskbar). If you close IE, the program will stop debugging. Try using a different browser (should be a drop down next to the green play button).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to IIS Manager.

Sites --> Add website --> Write the physical path of your solution folder --> Change port 80 with something random and this should work .